# SSL Certificate troubles

Tags: ssl

I'm new to Linux, currently learning.

Base system is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, apache2.4

Whenever I try to add a SSL certificate i get the NXDOMAIN error, and it fails.

I have added an A record in DNS for the domain i'm trying to add certificates to.

Can anyone advise on this?

Comment: Not sure where comments are here:

dig "domain.com" returns fine, and shows a A record on my DNS server.

Comment: Not sure where comments are here:

dig "domain.com" returns fine, and shows a A record on my DNS server.

as does nslookup.

Command Run:


User@Servername:~$ sudo ./certbot-auto --apache --agree-tos --rsa-key-size 4096 --email Company@Email.com --redirect -d Domain.com

Comment: Returns:

Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for Domain.com
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. Domain.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for Domain.com

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: Domain.com
   Type:   None
   Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for Domain.com